# Spark + BigQuery: `InvocationTargetException: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack`

Tags: apache-spark, google-bigquery, protobuf-java

I've tried this with all combinations of:

- Python and Scala
- JDK 8 and JDK 11
- Spark 3.1.2 and Spark 3.3.1

and I get the same error. Here I will show the Scala + JDK 11 + Spark 3.3.1 attempt, but as I said, all combinations result in the same error:

1. Set JAVA_HOME for JDK 11, SPARK_HOME for Spark 3.3.1 and run the Scala spark-shell with BigQuery + GCS connector configured:

```bash
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 11)
export SPARK_HOME=~/opt/spark/spark-3.3.1-bin-hadoop3-scala2.13
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-shell \
  -c spark.hadoop.fs.AbstractFileSystem.gs.impl=com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFS \
  -c spark.hadoop.fs.gs.impl=com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem \
  --packages "com.google.cloud.spark:spark-bigquery-with-dependencies_2.13:0.28.0,com.google.cloud.bigdataoss:gcs-connector:hadoop3-2.2.10"
```

2. Setup a dummy test dataframe:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val df = spark.createDataFrame(
  java.util.List.of(
    Row(1, "foo"),
    Row(2, "bar")
  ), StructType(
    StructField("a", IntegerType) ::
    StructField("b", StringType) ::
    Nil))

df.show()
```

That results in:

```
+---+---+
|  a|  b|
+---+---+
|  1|foo|
|  2|bar|
+---+---+
```

3. Write the simple dataframe to BigQuery:

```scala
df.write.
  format("bigquery").
  mode("overwrite").
  option("project", "<redacted>").
  option("parentProject", "<redacted>").
  option("dataset", "<redacted>").
  option("credentials", bigquery_credentials_b64).
  option("temporaryGcsBucket", "<redacted>").
  save("test_table")
```

I get:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
  at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:137)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3467)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$300(FileSystem.java:174)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3574)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3521)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:540)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:365)
  at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.SparkBigQueryUtil.getUniqueGcsPath(SparkBigQueryUtil.java:127)
  at com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.SparkBigQueryUtil.createGcsPath(SparkBigQueryUtil.java:108)
  ... 75 elided
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/google/api/ClientProto.registerAllExtensions(Lcom/google/protobuf/ExtensionRegistryLite;)V @4: invokevirtual
  Reason:
    Type 'com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage$GeneratedExtension' (current frame, stack[1]) is not assignable to 'com/google/protobuf/ExtensionLite'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @4
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'com/google/protobuf/ExtensionRegistryLite' }
    stack: { 'com/google/protobuf/ExtensionRegistryLite', 'com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage$GeneratedExtension' }
  Bytecode:
    0000000: 2ab2 0002 b600 032a b200 04b6 0003 2ab2
    0000010: 0005 b600 03b1

  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
  at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
  at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
  at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:135)
  ... 83 more
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/google/api/ClientProto.registerAllExtensions(Lcom/google/protobuf/ExtensionRegistryLite;)V @4: invokevirtual
  Reason:
    Type 'com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage$GeneratedExtension' (current frame, stack[1]) is not assignable to 'com/google/protobuf/ExtensionLite'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @4
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'com/google/protobuf/ExtensionRegistryLite' }
    stack: { 'com/google/protobuf/ExtensionRegistryLite', 'com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage$GeneratedExtension' }
  Bytecode:
    0000000: 2ab2 0002 b600 032a b200 04b6 0003 2ab2
    0000010: 0005 b600 03b1

  ... 5 elided and 88 more
```

Comment: Could you confirm if you're writing spark dataframe to BigQuery? Does this [documentation](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector) help you?

Comment: yes, it's a spark DataFrame. I showed the Spark Scala code that I'm using to create the test data frame in the main post.

Comment: It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP [support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/). Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) describing your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is that custom shaded .jars are required. Managed Spark environments like Databricks and Amazon EMR have solved these issues, but this is actually quite complex  to get running in a local environment with spark-shell.